# Noogra Nuts freezes my Windows 8 computer in classic mode

Tags: windows-8, gaming, windows-store, windows-8-games

I installed [Noogra Nuts](http://www.bengigi.com/) using the Windows Store. When I try to play Noogra Nuts by selecting Classic mode, my computer freezes.

Specs:

Noogra Nuts

```
systeminfo | findstr /B /C:"OS Name" /C:"OS Version"
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 8 Pro
OS Version:                6.2.9200 N/A Build 9200

systeminfo | findstr /B /C:"System Manufacturer" /C:"System Model"
System Manufacturer:       Apple Inc.
System Model:              MacBookPro5,5
```